# kubernetes weave route not automatically added

Tags: kubernetes, weave

I'm having a weird issue with k8s and weave.
I'm still new on k8s, I will try to explain my issue as accurate as possible.

We have 2 namespaces set up on k8s. One service(service 1) has CIDR: 10.32.0.0/22, another service(service 2) has CIDR: 172.168.0.0/16. I added a new node to existing cluster. I installed kubelet, kubeadm and kubectl on the new node. I ran kubeadm join command and the new added node show up correctly, and weave has started container inside new node successfully too.

However, I checked route table of the node, one of the service CIDR is not added. This is weird, why ip of service 2 is added to route but ip of service 1 is not added?

I manually ran `route add -net 10.32.0.0/12 dev weave` to include service 1's ip and everything works fine now. What kind of config I'm missing here?

Any advice is appreciated.

**kubernetes version:1.7.3**

Comment: Usually I see service IP address in the same subnet. Not sure about your cluster configuration.  So you’re creating the service name with IP specified?

Comment: thank you, one service is created with ip specified. The other service is actually kube-system, which is created by kubernetes. Not sure if my question makes sense. I'm also reading more documentations on k8s and weave, hope i can understand my issue better.

Comment: I've run into this same problem on Kubernetes 1.21.1. The only node that didn't get the route was the control-plane node, for whatever that's worth.